# Should this answer be removed?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, disputed-flags

I am still learning how best to moderate and wondered what the communities' thoughts on this are. I flagged https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825420/692942 as "Not an Answer" and the outcome was "Disputed".

I wondered why as looking at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22821687/692942) it is clear to me that the OP has just posted his attempt at a solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822027/692942) that has already been provided.

Should it not have been added as an update to the question? Or was I wrong to flag it?

Comment: Are the negative votes to say I shouldn't have asked this? Just trying to learn how best to moderate.

Comment: I think they may be voting to disagree, which is stupid as you're asking for advice. I've upvoted

Comment: Most likely the negative votes are from people who disagree that the answer should have been removed. I'd be with them **if** you had come here saying "I'm sure I'm right!!! How can anyone disagree?" but you're not, so I don't agree with their votes.

Comment: @Louis Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I think I'm a lot clearer on the whole topic now. All good answers +1.

Comment: Thanks @KateGregory I didn't realise that's what it meant. So the "Disputed" is because my flag "Not an answer" is actually invalid because technically it is an answer. Makes sense.

Comment: @Lankymart correct flags can end up `disputed` - just means someone said "invalid flags" - you might be wrong or you might be right

Comment: Am I missing something here? This code is an obvious answer with a solution for the problem and while I barely know any VB, it does look pretty different from the code in the other answer. Why is this being considered as not an answer?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel How is it different? [Ekkehard.Horner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner) suggests using `ExecuteGlobal` and `.ReadAll()` to read the ASP file and execute it using `ExecuteGlobal`. The OPs answer is **exactly** that, just his implementation. Does that mean when someone puts effort into answering a question an OP can just come a long regurgitate their answer and take the credit? Seems a bit unjust to me.

Comment: What credit is supposedly taken? Both answers have upvotes and Ekkehard even states himself that Dennis' answer deserves credit. Martha's comment should be taken into account: *Yeah, the problem with this answer is that it omits the actual possibly-hard step: importing the contents of the .asp file.* These two answers complement eachother, nothing more.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel We will see. I have no problem with an upvote but Ekkehard's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't have flagged it.

It doesn't belong in the question itself, because it provides no additional information to benefit the actual question.

Having a superfluous answer of the OP's exact solution doesn't distract from the website. Whereas having answers which should have been comments or are questions themselves does, as it breaks the Stack Overflow format and clutters the page.

Comment: Richard Tingle has said the same thing, that is interesting because I would have thought it belonged more in the question as an "update" to show that yes I've tried your solution and this is the outcome. Is that not a recommended practice?

Comment: @Lankymart: nope, not at all. If it answers the question, it's not meant to be part of the question. I've frequently asked users to post that as a self-answer if there isn't already an answer which is basically the same thing. In this instance, I think it's a bit borderline, but I don't have too much VB experience to say.

Comment: The answer is a bit pointless, but it's not part of the question. Personally I would just upvote the solution that helped.

Comment: @Lankymart Does removing that "UPDATE" line help you see that it is an answer to his own question?

Comment: @animuson Not really (I see your point though). The answer is just *his* regurgitation of Ekkehard.Horner answer he should have just commented that it work and accepted the answer. If everyone did that good quality answers would go unnoticed. Going to wait and see whether the OP marks his own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

What you've got there *is* an answer. It may be a flawed answer but that does not make it "not an answer."

You have suggested that it be part of the question. However, **it is actually part of our editorial practices to require that solution be posted as answers.** So if the OP posts a question and finds a solution and edits the question to add the solution, we should prompt them to remove the solution from the question and post it as a separate answer. (I prefer not to edit the question myself to remove the added solution *right away* because if the OP is not quick to submit their answer there is useful information that will be missing for a while. And I can't submit an answer in their name.)

Answer (score 8):

It is 100% not part of the question, if anything it would confuse the question as there would appear to be no problem. Questions should be used soley to state the problem as clearly as possible. Answers should give a solution to that problem and anything else either shouldn't exist or should be a comment.

This answer does answer the question so it is an answer; albeit a bad one. It states what to do but not why. It also does not look identical to existing answers so I would argue it should stay (up/downvote as you see fit as always)

Comment: It's in the context of a specific solution though, I've seen a lot of question that add an update to say what did or didn't work is this bad practice then? If it is how do OPs communicate their solution?

Comment: @Lankymart a simple tick of the accepted answer if that solved it,  a self answer if they used their own solution

Comment: @Lankymart There's a difference between the OP saying, "The problem still exists but if I try X, then Y happens." versus "I've solved the problem!". The former could be added to the question, the latter is an answer. However, in the former case, it may well be that the *original* problem *was* fixed and now the OP is encountering a *new* problem. In such cases, I prompt them to post their answer or accept the answer that fixed the issue and post a new question explaining the new problem.